# Can't find a row in my table sqlite3 table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sql-update, replace

I'm trying to set up a simple edit feature for an object in one of my tables.  Here is my current code which I've seen online and in books but it doesn't work

```
def edit
    @fire_chief = FireChief.find(params[:id])
 end
```

All I have to do is figure out how to edit a specific Fire Chief in list view and I can keep programming, but I'm stuck.

The error I'm recieving is "Couldn't find FireChief without an ID"

If I use this little snippet of code it finds the edit form fine

```
def edit
    @fire_chief = FireChief.last
 end
```

But it always pulls up the last entry to be edited.  I need it to pull the entry that i click...might be the 1st, 3rd, or 5th, etc.  I know a lot of this is redundant, but I just want to be clear on what I'm trying to do.

This is my routes file:

```
resource :timesheet do
    resource :command_officer
    resources :fire_chief
    resources :fire_fighters
    resource :safety_officer
    resources :emts
    resources :hazmat_specialists
    resources :command_vehicles
    resources :engines
    resources :emergency_supports
    resources :hazmat_units
    resources :field_units
    resources :pumpers
    resources :tankers
    resources :rescue_units
end
end
```

I just changed the resource :fire_chief to be plural, so now its this resources :fire_chief

But I'm getting this error now:

Routing Error

uninitialized constant FireChiefController

Comment: What does the code in the view look like? Also, in the `development.log` file under the `log` directory, you should be able to see the `params` hash that got passed to your controller.

Comment: What URL are you using to access that action, and what does `rake routes` show for your FireChief controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get an `id` or any other data you need from `params` you have to pass the data inside the url like this example:

`/firechief/2/edit`

This way your `edit` method will know the id and the method will work. You can set this manually inside your routes, making a route like this:

```
get  "/firechief/:firechief_id/edit" => "firechiefs#edit", as => :edit_firechief
```

Or if you are using `resources` inside your routes, it shall work by default.

If you actually does not want to pass any data inside your url, you could implement a session based solution. Create a method to store the `id` of the `firechief` inside a controller that fits your needs, or just add this line if you want to create the session inside a method (like `firechief#create`) you already has:

```
session[:firechief] = #here you add the id of the firechief you want to store
```

Now on your controller you can do this:

```
def edit
    @fire_chief = FireChief.find(session[:firechief])
end
```

Comment: Thanks everyone that responded...the problem was with routes file.